# find and modify highest n values in a 2D array in fortran

Tags: arrays, sorting, fortran, max, fortran90

I have a 2D real number array and I want to locate the n highest values and assign these highest values to 1 and all others to 0.

The following code does this correctly by using MAXLOC inside a loop to find a maximum value, change it to -9999, thus excluding it from the next iteration of the loop. At the end all the -9999 values are assigned to 1. The problem is that this approach is unworkably slow. It's fine for [this sample dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oOCkSr4f3F8Ujcds-LsPCr1Sf18kWXy8/view?usp=share_link) which has 8604 cells, of which the highest 50 are selected, but the real data have 108183756 cells, of which I need to find the highest 1672137. I'd appreciate any help.

```
PROGRAM mapalgebra
  IMPLICIT NONE

  REAL, DIMENSION(64,126) :: n
  REAL, DIMENSION(64,126) :: a
  REAL, DIMENSION(64,126) :: r
  REAL, DIMENSION(64,126) :: ine
  REAL, DIMENSION(64,126) :: s
  REAL, DIMENSION(64,126) :: p
  REAL, DIMENSION(64,126) :: TTP
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(64,126) :: newlu
  INTEGER :: row,col,max_rows,max_cols,i, j,demand, si
  INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE :: AR1(:)
  
  newlu = 0
  
  max_rows=64
  max_cols=126

  OPEN(UNIT=1, FILE="urb.txt") 
  OPEN(UNIT=2, FILE="acc.txt") 
  OPEN(UNIT=4, FILE="ran.txt")  
  OPEN(UNIT=5, FILE="lu1.txt") 
  OPEN(UNIT=7, FILE="suit.txt") 
  OPEN(UNIT=8, FILE="pob.txt") 

  DO row = 1,max_rows
      READ(1,*) (n(row,col),col=1,max_cols)
  END DO

  DO row = 1,max_rows
      READ(2,*) (a(row,col),col=1,max_cols)
  END DO
  
  DO row = 1,max_rows
      READ(4,*) (r(row,col),col=1,max_cols)
  END DO

  DO row = 1,max_rows
      READ(5,*) (ine(row,col),col=1,max_cols)
  END DO
  
  DO row = 1,max_rows
      READ(7,*) (s(row,col),col=1,max_cols)
  END DO

  DO row = 1,max_rows
      READ(8,*) (p(row,col),col=1,max_cols)
  END DO
  
  demand = 50
  
  print *, "Land use demand is : ", demand

  TTP = (ine+n+r+a+s)*p   !population weighted model, (inertia+nhood+randomness+accessibility+suitability)*population
  
  si = SIZE(SHAPE(TTP))   ! Get number of dimensions
                          ! in array
  print *, "TTP has : ", si  , " dimensions"                    
                          
  ALLOCATE (AR1(si))       ! Allocate AR1 to number
                          ! of dimensions in array
   
  DO i=1,demand
   AR1=MAXLOC (TTP)
   !print *, "MAXLOC (TTP) : ", AR1
   TTP(AR1(1),AR1(2)) = -9999
   newlu(AR1(1),AR1(2)) = 1
  END DO
  
  OPEN(UNIT=3, FILE="output.txt", ACTION="write", STATUS="replace")
  WRITE(3,11) 'ncols 126'
  WRITE(3,11) 'nrows 64'
  WRITE(3,11) 'xllcorner 461229.21505206'
  WRITE(3,11) 'yllcorner 4478822.89048722'
  WRITE(3,11) 'cellsize 99.38142966 '
  WRITE(3,11) 'NODATA_value 0 '
  11 format(A,I3)
  DO i=1,max_rows
    WRITE(3,*) (newlu(i,j), j=1,max_cols)
  END DO
 CLOSE (1)
 CLOSE (2)
 CLOSE (3)
 CLOSE (4)
 CLOSE (5)
 CLOSE (7)
 CLOSE (8)
     
END PROGRAM mapalgebra
```

Comment: Yours is a very slow sorting algorithm (some variant of selection sort). In C++ you could use std::nth_element. Maybe look up typical implementations of this and try to recode in Fortran? Otherwise, you could adopt a divide-and-conquer approach: first find minimum and maximum cell values, divide the range into a modest number of bins, if you tally the count in each bin then only one of the bins will need sorting.

Comment: @lastchance thanks very much for the rapid answer. Good idea to look at C++ implementations and try to recode, I'll look into this. And the bin suggestion is ingenious, I'll see if I can try to implement it! Thanks!

Comment: Seems like the `WHERE()` keyword is what you are looking for to set the values above the threshold. But finding this threshold value requires some user-calculated statistics.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution. The idea is to count the number of elements that are `>= v0`, and to find `v0` by bisection until the number of elements is `k`. The overall complexity is `O(N)`. No sorting is involved, and no data is moved. There's a (very) slight complication in the case where among the k largest elements, several one are equal to the minimum value.

```
Program test
    implicit none

    real, allocatable :: a(:)
    integer, parameter :: n=108183756, k=1672137

    integer :: k0, i, kk
    real :: v0, v1, v2, vmin, vmax

    allocate(a(n))
    call random_number(a)

    vmax = maxval(a,dim=1)
    vmin = minval(a,dim=1)
    write(*,*) vmin,vmax
    
    if (count(a == vmax) > k) then
        ! special case
        kk = k
        do i = 1, n
            if (a(i) == vmax .and. kk > 0) then
                a(i) = 1.0
                kk = kk - 1
            else
                a(i) = 0.0
            end if
        end do
    
    else
    
        ! ...
        v1 = vmax
        v2 = vmin ! the v2 initial value could be refined
                  ! in the case where k << n
    
        ! Reduce the [v1,v2] interval by bisection
        v0 = (v1+v2)/2.0
        k0 = count(a >= v0)
        do
            write(*,*) "-----",v1,v2,v0,k0
            if (k0 == k) exit   ! perfect value
            if (v0 == v2 .or. v0 == v1) exit   ! see below
            if (k0 > k) then
                v2 = v0
            else
                v1 = v0
            end if
            v0 = (v1+v2)/2.0
            k0 = count(a >= v0)
        end do
    
        ! If the previous loop exited because v0 was equal to 
        ! either v1 or v2, then it means that there were no 
        ! more possible real value between v1 and v2.
        ! In turns it means that there are several elements of 
        ! a(:) that are equal to the minimum value (v2) among
        ! the k largest. This has to be taken into account
        if (k0 == k) then
            kk = 0
        else
            v0 = v1
            kk = k-count(a >= v0)
        end if
        do i = 1, n
            if (a(i) >= v0) then
                a(i) = 1.0
            else if (a(i) >= v2 .and. kk > 0) then
                a(i) = 1.0
                kk = kk - 1
            else
                a(i) = 0.0
            end if
        end do
    
    end if
    
    write(*,*) count(a == 1.0)
            
End
```

**Edit: possible optimizations**

- As mentioned in the comments, a better initial guess of `v2` (instead of vmax) could save some iterations. For instance `v2 = vmax - (vmax-vmin)*k/n` (which would be appropriate for a uniform distribution of the values). An additional loop before the main loop would be needed if the initial guess was too large.
- At some point, when the element count between v1 and v2 is "low enough", it would be faster to sort these elements instead of continuing the iterations.

Comment: Small thing, by "dichotomy" do you mean "bisection"?

Comment: Maybe. In french I would use almost indifferently "dichotomie" or "bissection" here, but in english it has maybe not the same meaning...

Comment: Ahhh, in English they mean somewhat different things, I've corrected the post.

Comment: @PierU this is a very neat and elegant solution. I'm very grateful. The solution I eventually came up with (before seeing your post) has some points in common but is certainly inferior and less efficient to your code, so I will try to adapt my code to yours. In the meantime I will post my own imperfect solution just in case it is of interest. Sorry I can't upvote, not enough rep.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestions of @lastchance I'm answering my own question with a less elegant solution than @PierU but worth posting I think because it is slightly different. The new code [(download link to the full dataset - 151 Mb)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Be_k8RReJeGpfeQMqlkUPJzvEC9fJFpn/view?usp=share_link) finds the highest n values (variable demand) using a masking approach within the MERGE function to create a new array "masked" containing all values greater than or equal to a certain threshold (binsize) in TTP. It does this without sorting the array TTP by adjusting binsize according to the number of cells in the new array "masked" after the MERGE operation. If there are too many cells, the binsize is decreased, if there are too few, the binsize is increased. If the algorithm "sticks" this is identified by variable "lt" which only takes value > 0 if binsize has been decreased and then subsequently increased without finding a solution. The loop terminates once the cell count in the new array is equal to the number of values desired (variable demand) or once no further improvement can be made. I'm sure this code can be improved, with reference to the solution suggested by @PierU. Thanks everyone!

```
 PROGRAM mapalgebra
  IMPLICIT NONE
  !gfortran assigntest2.f90 -mcmodel=medium -o assigntest2
  REAL, DIMENSION(8966,12066) :: TTP
  REAL, DIMENSION(8966,12066) :: masked
  REAL :: maxv,minv,rangev, bincut,binsize,binstart,binstartold,increment
  !real, intent(in) :: my_array(:)
  !real, allocatable :: masked(::)
  REAL, DIMENSION(8966,12066) :: newlu
  INTEGER :: row,col,max_rows,max_cols,i, j,demand, si,counts,gt,lt
  INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE :: AR1(:)
  
  newlu = 0.0
  
  max_rows=8966
  max_cols=12066

  OPEN(UNIT=1, FILE="TTPbig.txt") 

  DO row = 1,max_rows
      READ(1,*) (TTP(row,col),col=1,max_cols)
  END DO
  
  demand = 1672137
  
  print *, "Land use demand is : ", demand

  maxv = maxval(TTP)
  minv = minval(TTP)
  rangev = maxv-minv
  binstart = 10.0
  counts = 0
  gt = 0
  lt = 0
  increment = 1.0
  print *, "TTP has maxval : ", maxv  , " minval ", minv, " and range ", rangev 
  
  DO WHILE ( counts .NE. demand )
     if (binstartold .EQ. binstart) EXIT
    bincut = rangev/binstart
    binsize = maxv-bincut
    print *, "Bin cut off = ", bincut  , " bin = ", binsize 
    print *, "binstartold = ", binstartold  , " binstart = ", binstart
    if (lt>0) then
        increment= increment/10
        gt=0
        lt=0
    end if
    binstartold = binstart
    masked = MERGE(TTP, 0., TTP>=binsize)
    counts = count(masked/=0)
    if (counts > demand) then
        gt=gt+1
        print *,counts
        print *, "too many cells, reducing binsize ", binstart
        binstart = binstart+increment
        print *,binstart
    else if (counts < demand) then
        lt=lt+gt
        print *,counts
        print *, "too few cells, increasing binsize ", binstart
        binstart = binstart-increment
        print *,binstart
    end if
  END DO 
  print *, "count = ",counts," and demand= ",demand
  where(masked/=0) newlu = 1
 
  !DO i=1,demand
   !AR1=MAXLOC (TTP)
   !!print *, "MAXLOC (TTP) : ", AR1
   !TTP(AR1(1),AR1(2)) = -9999
   !newlu(AR1(1),AR1(2)) = 1
  !END DO
  
  OPEN(UNIT=3, FILE="output.txt", ACTION="write", STATUS="replace")
  WRITE(3,11) 'ncols 12066'
  WRITE(3,11) 'nrows 8966'
  WRITE(3,11) 'xllcorner -42274.14800538'
  WRITE(3,11) 'yllcorner 3975389.72101546'
  WRITE(3,11) 'cellsize 99.38142966 '
  WRITE(3,11) 'NODATA_value 0 '
  11 format(A,I3)
  DO i=1,max_rows
    WRITE(3,*) (newlu(i,j), j=1,max_cols)
  END DO
 CLOSE (1)
 CLOSE (2)
 CLOSE (3)
 CLOSE (4)
 CLOSE (5)
 CLOSE (7)
 CLOSE (8)
     
END PROGRAM mapalgebra
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following algorithm

1. First find the threshold value `x` of the array that corresponds to the `demand`-th rank of an `array`. It uses the `qsort()` algorithm from the portable library to rank the items and then it picks the required item from the end of the list (highest value)

   ```
   function find_top_n_value(array, demand) result(x)
   use ifport
   real, intent(in) :: array(:)
   integer, intent(in) :: demand
   real :: sorted(size(array))
   real :: x
   integer :: n

       n = size(array)
       sorted = array
       call qsort(sorted, n, SIZEOF(x), compr)

       x = sorted(n-demand+1)

   end function

   INTEGER(2) FUNCTION compr(arg1, arg2)
   real, intent(in) :: arg1, arg2
       if(arg1>arg2) then
           compr = 1
       else if(arg2>arg1) then
           compr = -1
       else
           compr = 0
       end if
   end function
   ```
2. Now use the `where()` statement to convert a copy of the array called `masked` into 0 and 1 values depending on where they fall on the threshold

   ```
   masked = array
   where(masked>= x)
       masked = 1.0
   else where
       masked = 0.0
   end where
   ```

In my example code

```
real :: x
real, parameter :: array(*) = [6.0, 5.5, 2.0, 8.0, 9.0, 4.0, 8.5]
real :: masked(size(array))
integer :: demand

print *, "Input  Array: ", array
demand = 3
x = find_top_n_value( array, 3)
print '(*(g0))', "Top #", demand ," value is ", x

masked = array
where(masked>= x)
    masked = 1.0
else where
    masked = 0.0
end where

print *, "Masked Array: ", masked
```

the results are:

```
 Input  Array:    6.000000       5.500000       2.000000       8.000000
   9.000000       4.000000       8.500000
Top #3 value is 8.000000
 Masked Array:   0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00   1.000000
   1.000000      0.0000000E+00   1.000000
```

where you can see the values that are 8 or more are 1.0 and the rest are zeros.

Comment: Nice solution! One small question - (1) ipfort looks like it requires the ifort fortran compiler, right?. (I'm using gfortran).

Comment: See if gfortran comes with a portability library that contains `qsort()` that is all it is used for. Or roll your own sorting routine.

Comment: Finding the threshold value becomes obvious once the input array is sorted. What is interesting is to find the value without sorting. @richjh there are plenty of code examples for the quicksort algorithm, for instance: https://gist.github.com/t-nissie/479f0f16966925fa29ea

Comment: @richjh One can  easily call the `qsort` function from the C standard library. And `ifport` most likely does exactly that for you. This module mostly gives you Fortran interfaces to well known C functions. In general, sorting routines implemented through a callback to a comoarison function are nicely general, but somewhat slow.

Comment: An example for an interface block for `qsort` is at https://bitbucket.org/LadaF/elmm/src/master/src/wallmodels.f90

Answer (score 1):

Like the other posters this first identifies the threshold value and then "binarises" (for want of a better word) the array.

This version uses QuickSelect (NOT QuickSort), in the hope of making it O(N) on average, rather than O(N log N) as in a sorted algorithm - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect

```
module libs
   use iso_fortran_env
   implicit none

contains

   !----------------------------------------------

   integer function partition( A, left, right ) result( i )
      real, intent(inout) :: A(:)
      integer, intent(in) :: left, right
      real AP
      integer j

      i = left
      call pivot( A(left:right) )
      Ap = A(left)

      do j = left + 1, right
         if ( A(j) < Ap ) then
            call swap( A(i+1), A(j) )
            i = i + 1
         end if
      end do
      call swap( A(left), A(i) )

   end function partition

   !----------------------------------------------

   recursive real function quickSelect( A, left, right, n ) result( res )
      real, intent(inout) :: A(:)
      integer, intent(in) :: left, right, n
      integer p

      if ( left == right ) then
         res = A(left)
      else
         p = partition( A, left, right )             ! A(p) will be in its correct place
         if ( p == n ) then
            res = A(p)                               ! if p == n then we're done
         else if ( p < n ) then
            res = quickSelect( A, p + 1, right, n )  ! check the RIGHT side ONLY 
         else
            res = quickSelect( A, left , p - 1, n )  ! check the LEFT side ONLY
         end if
      end if

   end function quickSelect

   !----------------------------------------------

   subroutine swap( a, b )
      real, intent(inout) :: a, b
      real t

      t = a
      a = b
      b = t

   end subroutine swap

   !----------------------------------------------

   subroutine pivot( A )
      real, intent(inout) :: A(:)
      integer p
      real r

      call random_number( r )
      p = 1 + size( A ) * r
      if ( p /= 1 ) call swap( A(1), A(p) )

   end subroutine pivot

   !----------------------------------------------

   subroutine binarise( A, An, n )
      real, intent(inout) :: A(:)
      real, intent(in) :: An
      real dummy(size(A))
      integer, intent(in) :: n
      integer counter, i

      counter = 0
      dummy = 0
      do i = 1, size( A )
         if ( A(i) > An ) then
            dummy(i) = 1.0
            counter = counter + 1
         end if
      end do
      do i = 1, size( A )
         if ( A(i) == An ) then
            dummy(i) = 1.0
            counter = counter + 1
            if ( counter == n ) exit    ! ignore further repeats
         end if
      end do

      A = dummy

   end subroutine binarise

end module libs

!=======================================================================

program main
   use libs
   implicit none
   real, allocatable :: A(:), dummy(:)
   real An
   integer left, right
   integer n
   character(len=*), parameter :: FMT = "( A, *( f4.1, 1x ) )"

   A = [ 5, 6, 4, 1, 8, 1, 5, 9 ]                ! array to be "binarised"
   n = 4                                         ! nth LARGEST element
   write( *, FMT ) "A(original)  = ", A
   write( *, *   ) "n = ", n

   ! Find the nth value
   left = 1;   right = size( A )
   dummy = A
   An = quickSelect( dummy, left, right, size(A) - n + 1 ) ! the cut-off value (which might be repeated)

   ! Binarise A
   call binarise( A, An, n )
   write( *, FMT ) "A(binarised) = ", A

end program main

!=======================================================================
```

Output (note that only one of the repeated 5's earns a "1.0" value):

```
A(original)  =  5.0  6.0  4.0  1.0  8.0  1.0  5.0  9.0
 n =            4
A(binarised) =  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

There have been four answers so far:

- mine, with a bisection approach
- the OP, with a binning approach as suggested by @lastchance in the comments
- @lastchance with a quickselect approach
- @JohnAlexiou with a quicksort approach

As stated by several contributor, the question is essentially about finding the k-th element in decreasing order, in an unordered list.

I have refined and improved my bisection routine (making it recursive, and fixing a few issues). I have also written a routine with a binning approach. And I compare the two to the quicksort and quickselect approachs. All of them are written to find the kth element in the *increasing* oder. Also, I do no longer manage the case where there are several elements equal to the searched value (the output is still correct, though).

Here is a benchmark for `n=108183756, k=16721370` in different cases:

```
$ gfortran -O3 klargest2.f90 && ./a.out 

 Input = uniform distribution
 --------------------------------
 quicksort           v =  0.154617488     time =   13.4908419    
 quickselect         v =  0.154617488     time =   1.18194902    
 bisection           v =  0.154617488     time =  0.724147022    
 binning             v =  0.154617488     time =  0.649156988    

 Input = non-uniform distribution
 --------------------------------
 quicksort           v =   2.39065681E-02 time =   13.4206972    
 quickselect         v =   2.39065681E-02 time =   1.28310299    
 bisection           v =   2.39065681E-02 time =  0.781505048    
 binning             v =   2.39065681E-02 time =   1.13891697    

 Input = highly non-uniform distribution
 --------------------------------
 quicksort           v =   3.69637343E-03 time =   14.0137014    
 quickselect         v =   3.69637343E-03 time =   1.20810306    
 bisection           v =   3.69637343E-03 time =  0.823186994    
 binning             v =   3.69637343E-03 time =   1.64031005
```

Observations:

- as expected, the quicksort approach is much slower than the others ones. The reason is that the data have to be constanly copied, moved, etc... The average complexity is O(N*log(N)), but it can be O(N**2) in the worst case (even if unlikely).
- the quikselect approach is 10 times faster. The reason is that quickselect does sort only what is needed to get to k-th element, and consequently the complexity is O(N) (but still with a worst case in O(N**2))

Comparing the binning and the bisection:

- the binning is slightly faster on a uniform distribution
- the bisection is faster on non-uniform distributions
- the bisection code is simpler

*Note that the binning approach is actually quite similar to the bisection approach, but instead of splitting the value range in 2, we split it in `NBIN` (10 in my example). The efficiency of the binning approach entirely relies on guessing in which bin the searched value is: this is easy for a uniform distribution, but much less easy in the general case.*

Comparing the bisection and quickselect

- the bisection is faster.
- both have a O(N) complexity, but in the worst case (although unlikely) the complexity of quickselect is O(N**2), while it is still O(N) for the bisection.
- the bisection does not modify the input array
- the quickselect code is much simpler

Here is the full test code, that you can run and modify:

```
MODULE kth_element
implicit none

CONTAINS    

    !*************************************************************************************
    real recursive function bisection(a,k,strict,v1,v2,k1,k2) result(val)
    !*************************************************************************************
    ! Finding the k-th value of a(:) in increasing order by bisection of a [v1;v2] interval,
    ! mostly without sorting or copying the data (see below)
    ! - At each step we have count(a<=v1) < k <= count(a<=v2)
    ! - If the number of elements in the interval falls below a hard-coded threshold, 
    !   we stop the bisection and explicitly sort the remaining elements.
    !   Drawback: a bit more memory occupation and (limited) data duplication
    !   Advantage: if strict is .true., sorting is more efficient for a small number 
    !              of elements
    ! - If the number of elements in the interval falls below 1/10th the input number
    !   of elements, these elements are copied to a new array.
    !   Drawback: a bit more memory occupation and (limited) data duplication
    !   Advantage: much less elements to count, and more cache friendly
    ! - if strict is .true., the returned value is a value of the input array, otherwise
    !   it is an arbitrary value such that count(a<=val) == k, potentially saving 
    !   some final recursion step
    !
    ! The complexity is O(n*log(n)) 
    !*************************************************************************************
    real, intent(in) :: a(:)
    integer, intent(in) :: k
    logical, intent(in),  optional :: strict
    real, intent(in), optional :: v1, v2
    integer, intent(in), optional :: k1, k2

    integer, parameter :: NTOSORT = 10000
    integer :: n, k0, kk1, kk2, i, j
    real :: v0, vv1, vv2, c
    logical :: strict___
    real, allocatable :: b(:)
    !*************************************************************************************
    n = size(a)
    strict___ = .true.; if (present(strict))  strict___ = strict
        
    if (strict___ .and. n <= NTOSORT) then
        b = a(:)
        call quickselect(b,1,n,k)
        val = b(k)
        return
    end if

    if (.not.present(v1)) then
        ! Search for the min value vv1 and max value vv2 (faster than using minval/maxval)
        ! Generally in the code, k = count(a <= v)
        vv1 = a(1); kk1 = 1
        vv2 = a(1); kk2 = n
        do i = 2, n
            if (a(i) >  vv2) then
                vv2 = a(i)
            else if (a(i) <  vv1) then
                vv1 = a(i)
                kk1 = 1
            else if (a(i) == vv1) then
                kk1 = kk1 + 1
            end if
        end do
    
        ! trivial cases
        if (k <= kk1) then
            val = vv1
            return
        end if
        if (k == n) then
            val = vv2
            return
        end if
    else
        vv1 = v1; kk1 = k1
        vv2 = v2; kk2 = k2
    end if
        
    ! Reduce the [v1,v2] interval by bisection
    v0 = 0.5*(vv1+vv2)
    ! if the middle value falls back on v1 or v2, then no middle value can be obtained
    ! we are at the solution
    if (v0 == vv2 .or. v0 == vv1) then 
        val = vv2
    else
        ! actual bisection
        k0 = count(a <= v0)
        if (.not.strict___ .and. k0 == k) then
            ! v0 is not necessarily a value present in a(:)
            val = v0
        else
            if (k0 >= k) then
                vv2 = v0; kk2 = k0
            else
                vv1 = v0; kk1 = k0
            end if
            if (kk2-kk1 <= n/10) then
                call extract(a,vv1,vv2,b,kk2-kk1)
                val = bisection(b,k-kk1,strict)
            else
                val = bisection(a,k,strict,vv1,vv2,kk1,kk2)
            end if
        end if
    end if
    
    end function bisection
            
    !*************************************************************************************
    recursive subroutine quicksort(a,ifirst,ilast)
    !*************************************************************************************
    ! Author: t-nissie
    ! License: GPLv3
    ! Gist: https://gist.github.com/t-nissie/479f0f16966925fa29ea 
    !*************************************************************************************
    real, intent(inout) :: a(:)
    integer, intent(in) :: ifirst, ilast
    real :: x, t
    integer n, i, j
    !*************************************************************************************  
    n = size(a)
    x = a( (ifirst+ilast) / 2 )
    i = ifirst
    j = ilast
    do
        do while (a(i) < x)
            i=i+1
        end do
        do while (x < a(j))
            j=j-1
        end do
        if (i >= j) exit
        t = a(i);  a(i) = a(j);  a(j) = t
        i=i+1
        j=j-1
    end do
    if (ifirst < i-1) call quicksort(a,ifirst,i-1)
    if (j+1 < ilast)  call quicksort(a,j+1,ilast)
    end subroutine quicksort
    
    !*************************************************************************************
    recursive subroutine quickselect(a,ifirst,ilast,k)
    !*************************************************************************************
    ! Author: t-nissie
    ! License: GPLv3
    ! Gist: https://gist.github.com/t-nissie/479f0f16966925fa29ea 
    !*************************************************************************************
    real, intent(inout) :: a(:)
    integer, intent(in) :: ifirst, ilast, k
    real :: x, t
    integer n, i, j
    !*************************************************************************************  
    n = size(a)
    x = a( (ifirst+ilast) / 2 )
    i = ifirst
    j = ilast
    do
        do while (a(i) < x)
            i=i+1
        end do
        do while (x < a(j))
            j=j-1
        end do
        if (i >= j) exit
        t = a(i);  a(i) = a(j);  a(j) = t
        i=i+1
        j=j-1
    end do
    if (ifirst < i-1 .and. k <= i-1) call quickselect(a,ifirst,i-1,k)
    if (j+1 < ilast  .and. k >= j+1) call quickselect(a,j+1,ilast,k)
    end subroutine quickselect

    !*************************************************************************************  
    pure subroutine extract(a,v1,v2,b,m)
    !*************************************************************************************  
    real, intent(in) :: a(:), v1, v2
    real, allocatable, intent(out) :: b(:)
    integer, intent(in) :: m
    integer :: i, j
    !*************************************************************************************  
    allocate( b(m) )
    j = 0
    do i = 1, size(a)
        if (a(i) > v1 .and. a(i) <= v2) then
            j = j + 1
            b(j) = a(i)
        end if
    end do
    end subroutine extract

    !*************************************************************************************
    real recursive function binning(a,k,strict,status) result(val)
    !*************************************************************************************
    real, intent(in) :: a(:)
    integer, intent(in) :: k
    logical, intent(in),  optional :: strict
    integer, intent(out), optional :: status
        
    integer, parameter :: NTOSORT = 10000, NBIN = 10
    integer :: kk(0:NBIN), n, i, ibin, nbin___, k1, k2
    real :: v(0:NBIN), vmin, vmax, v1, v2
    logical :: strict___
    real, allocatable :: b(:)
    !*************************************************************************************
    n = size(a)
    if (present(status)) status = 0
    strict___ = .true.; if (present(strict))  strict___ = strict

    if (k<1 .or. k>n) then
        if (present(status)) then
            status = 1
            return
        else
            error stop "wrong k value or empty array"
        end if
    end if
    
    if (n <= NTOSORT) then
        b = a(:)
        call quickselect(b,1,n,k)
        val = b(k)
        return
    end if

    ! Search for the min and max values (faster than using minval/maxval)
    vmin = a(1); vmax = a(1)
    do i = 2, n
        if (a(i) > vmax) then
            vmax = a(i)
        else if (a(i) < vmin) then
            vmin = a(i)
        end if
    end do
        
    ! trivial case
    if (vmin == vmax) then
        val = vmin
        return
    end if
    
    ! building nbin bin boundaries
    v = [(vmin + ibin*(vmax-vmin)/NBIN, ibin=0,NBIN)]
    v(nbin) = vmax  ! forcing, just in case
    ! reducing the number of bins if some boundaries and equal to each others
    nbin___ = NBIN
    ibin = 1
    do
        if (ibin > nbin___) exit
        if (v(ibin) == v(ibin-1)) then
            v(ibin-1:nbin___-1) = v(ibin:nbin___)
            nbin___ = nbin___ - 1
        else
            ibin = ibin + 1
        end if
    end do
    
    kk(:) = -1 ! bin counter initialization
    ! estimate in which bin the k-th value may be, based on a uniform distribution hypothesis
    ibin = ceiling(nbin___*real(k)/n)
    ! count the number of elements for this bin, and explore the next bins if not enough
    do 
        if (ibin == nbin___) then
            kk(ibin) = n
        else
            kk(ibin) = count( a <= v(ibin) )
        end if
        if (kk(ibin) >= k) exit
        ibin = ibin+1
    end do
    ! explore the previous bins is needed
    do 
        if (ibin == 0) exit
        if (kk(ibin-1) >= 0) exit ! the previous bin has already been explored and rejected
        kk(ibin-1) = count( a <= v(ibin-1) )
        if (kk(ibin-1) < k) exit ! the current bin is the right one 
        ibin = ibin - 1
    end do

    if (ibin == 0) then
        val = v(ibin)
    else if (.not.strict___ .and. kk(ibin) == k) then
        val = v(ibin)
    else
        ! recursion on this bin
        v1 = v(ibin-1); k1 = kk(ibin-1)
        v2 = v(ibin)  ; k2 = kk(ibin)
        call extract(a,v1,v2,b,k2-k1)
        val = binning(b,k-k1,strict,status)
    end if
    
    end function binning

END MODULE kth_element




Program test

    use kth_element
    implicit none

    real, allocatable :: a(:), b(:)
    integer, parameter :: n=108183756, k=16721370
    integer :: i, nseed, iseed
    integer(8) :: tic, toc, rate
    real :: v0, v1, v2, v3, v4
    
    allocate(a(n))
    call random_seed(nseed)
    
    !iseed = 0
    !do 
    
        !call random_seed(put=[(iseed+i,i=0,nseed-1)])
        call random_number(a)
        
        do i = 1, 3
     
            write(*,*)
            if (i == 1) then
                write(*,*) "Input = uniform distribution"
            else if (i == 2) then
                a(:) = a(:)**2
                write(*,*) "Input = non-uniform distribution"
            else if (i == 3) then
                a(:) = a(:)**1.5
                write(*,*) "Input = highly non-uniform distribution"
            end if
            write(*,*) "--------------------------------"

            call system_clock(tic,rate)
            b = a(:)
            call quicksort(b,1,n)
            v0 = b(k)
            call system_clock(toc,rate)
            write(*,*) "quicksort           v =", v0, "time =",(toc-tic)/real(rate)

            call system_clock(tic,rate)
            b = a(:)
            call quickselect(b,1,n,k)
            v1 = b(k)
            call system_clock(toc,rate)
            write(*,*) "quickselect         v =", v1, "time =",(toc-tic)/real(rate)

            call system_clock(tic,rate)
            v2 = bisection(a,k)
            call system_clock(toc,rate)
            write(*,*) "bisection           v =", v2, "time =",(toc-tic)/real(rate)
  
            call system_clock(tic,rate)
            v3 = binning(a,k)
            call system_clock(toc,rate)
            write(*,*) "binning             v =", v3, "time =",(toc-tic)/real(rate)

            !if (v3 /= v2) then
            !   write(*,*) "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", iseed
            !   stop
            !end if
            
        end do

        !iseed = iseed + 1
    !end do
    
End Program
```

Comment: Also, in external quicksort with callback, there is a very considerable cost of calling the comparison fumctiin through the callback. A custom quicksort directly applied to the data can be much faster (by some constant multiplier).

Comment: Added the quickselect case...

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I am using a quicksort (and quickselect) code without callback.

Comment: Good, I assumed you might be comparing directly with the code im the other answer because you referenced it.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава The full code (including quicksort) is in my answer. I just picked one on the web, without trying to optimize it, but it looks a pretty standard one.

Comment: @PierU very informative post & code, I was wondering about comparative performance. In my case, as well as being slower, sorting has the disadvantage of requiring the 2D array to be reshaped to 1D before sorting (right?). Ideally would to allocate demand to a 2D array in place. And speed is crucial - the  given case (n=108183756, +k=16721370) is a land cover map of Spain, but I'd like to be able to apply to all Europe.

Comment: I have written the routines for 1D arrays, but it's not complicated to modify then for 2D arrays. Actually the simplest way for that is to write the dummy argument for the array with explicit shape rather than assumed shape (i.e. `real, intent(in) :: a(n)` with `n` passed as an argument, rather than `real, intent(in) :: a(:)`: like this, thanks to the versatility of the legacy Fortran interfaces, a 2D array (or 3D, whatever...) can be passed to the routine as if it was a 1D array.

Comment: The average complexity of QuickSelect is O(N). Essentially this comes from only having to consider one side of each partition at each stage (unlike QuickSort), whence: N + N/2 + N/4 + N/8 + ...=2N. The worst case will be even rarer if the pivot element about which you partition is chosen at random (as in my post, but not in your example drawn from the web). You are correct that the need to move/swap elements around slows things down a lot, though.